Creating User Friendly Email Alias for Plus Email Address
We got a plus email address in our GitLab ticketing page. Example gitlab+syetm-js3qn-2jsk@company13.com This will be our ticketing system email address that any email send to this address will be converted into a ticket in the GitLab service desk page. Actual mailbox of this address is at gitlab@company13.com
Ticketing system tickets are created when mails are sent to gitlab+syetm-js3qn-2jsk@company13.com address only and not sending to real email address gitlab@company13.com. So we need to give gitlab+syetm-js3qn-2jsk@company13.com address to our users to send their ticketing requests,
But the address gitlab+syetm-js3qn-2jsk@company13.com, is too long and difficult to remember, we want to create shorten form of it using alias or creating a distribution list and add this address as a member.
What I did so far is, I created a mail contact for gitlab+syetm-js3qn-2jsk@company13.com and added that mail contact to a distribution list as a member. Example systemsupport@company13.com is distribution list email address. When I send a mail to distribution list address, it end up with a mail loop and mail delivery failure.
Mail events shows as a cause for the failure is Exchange server sent out the mail to outside and it flapped between some external servers and delivery failed. Theoretically this possible because when we create a mail contact for a email address, it is considered as an external email address.
We are in Exchange online environment and we don't have hybrid mail setup.
I would kindly expect a possible solution for this. Any expert please help me here?

welcome, what is the research you have done sofar to solve this problem on your own? I found 10 tutorials at least... https://www.codetwo.com/userguide/exchange-rules-pro/rewrite-senders-address.htm

Thanks for the comment. I did quite lot, but unfortunately, neither worked. Could you point to the path?

does the provided tutorial not work?

I'm not quite sure it is related.

Can it be done through mail flow rule? If anyone know about it or any other possible solution, please let me know?
